# Setting wireless printer (Epson SX210) up?

Tags: printer, network-printer

I'm having some problems with my new Epson SX210 All-in-one. It should have wifi-compatibility. However, there are no any kind of instructions for setting up the wifi sharing. I got the machine working via usb, but I also need to use it on other computers at my house.

I've made it "shared printer" on my laptop, which it is plugged in via usb. However, other pcs on my network are not able to see it when looking for wireless printers.

Comment: ok, first of all what version of windows installed in all computers. Have you done all the procedures listed in  http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/networking/expert/honeycutt_july2.mspx

Comment: Every pc has Windows 7 installed. I'm gonna check that link. Thanks! I'll comment here when done :) Other advices?

Answer (score 1):

When you set it to share from your machine, it is actually shared directly on your machine, not through the printer.

In order for the other machines to print to it, you will need them to connect to your machine then install the printer.

However, I cannot see Wireless in the specification sheet, so I do not think this is a wireless enabled printer - sorry. Looks like wherever you bought it from had the wrong spec sheet up. (Unless I have looked it up wrong).

Comment: I only see USB as well, so you will need to do Printer Sharing through one of the PCs on the network as Wil suggested.

Comment: Oh yeah hahaha, I just discovered I had bought the wrong printer. I'm going to buy the another one tomorrow. Thanks for the help everyone! (Yeah I'm a bit stupid sometimes). There was a pile of the other printers and I took one, seems that it wasn't the right one :-D